# Assume that ($a_n$) converges to a and ($b_n$) converges to b. Prove that ($a_n-b_n$) converges to $a-b$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, triangle-inequality

I used a similar mean to the one that solves $a_n+b_n$ converges to a+b. However, I found it to be difficult to solve $a_n-b_n$ = $a-b$, since the reverse triangle inequality only suggests $\mid a_n-a\mid - \mid b_n - b \mid \; < \; \mid a_n-a-b_n+b \mid \; = \; \mid (a_n-b_n)-(a-b) \mid$. However, $\mid a_n-a\mid - \mid b_n - b \mid \; <\; \epsilon$ does not necessarily indicate $\mid (a_n-b_n)-(a-b) \mid \; < \; \epsilon$. What can I do?

Comment: Note that $\lvert (a_n-b_n)-(a-b)\rvert=\lvert(a_n-a)+(b-b_n)\vert$.

Comment: Extending the comment of @NickPeterson, given $~\epsilon > 0, ~\exists ~N_1, N_2~$ such that $~n \geq N_1 \implies |a_n - a| < \epsilon/2, ~~n \geq N_2 \implies |b_n - b| < \epsilon/2.~$ Now, set $~N = \max(N_1,N_2).$

Comment: Prove that $(-b_n)$ converges to $-b$, note that $a_n-b_n=a_n+(-b_n)$, and use your previous result.